Conexión a SQL desde Visual Studio
estudio Ingeniería en Sistemas Computacionales y tengo un problema con mi práctica de taller de bases de datos. Tengo una base en PHP My Admin y debo conectarme a ella desde Visual Studio, tengo estas tres clases:
Program,EFContext,Customers
La base de datos a la que debe conectarse se llama 'taller' y la tabla se llama 'customers'. Al compilarlo trabaja...más o menos, me deja utilizar la opción de alta y puedo registrar los datos, pero en la base de datos no se ve reflejado el cambio y así con las demás opciones. ¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar el error? Llevo varios días modificando, tratando de encontrar qué falla...gracias de antemano!
Estos son los códigos:
//Clase Program
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DatosEnTablaEntityFrameworkCore
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool exit = false;

            while (!exit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Seleccione una opción:");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Alta (Crear)");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Baja (Eliminar)");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Consulta (Leer)");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Modificación (Actualizar)");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Salir");

                var option = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (option)
                {
                    case "1":
                        CreateCustomer();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        DeleteCustomer();
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        ReadCustomers();
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        UpdateCustomer();
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        exit = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Opción no válida. Intente nuevamente.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void CreateCustomer()
        {
            using (var context = new EFContext())
            {
                Console.Write("Nombre del Cliente: ");
                var customerName = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Nombre del Contacto: ");
                var contactName = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Dirección: ");
                var address = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Ciudad: ");
                var city = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Código Postal: ");
                var postalCode = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("País: ");
                var country = Console.ReadLine();

                var newCustomer = new customers
                {
                    CustomerName = customerName,
                    ContactName = contactName,
                    Address = address,
                    City = city,
                    PostalCode = postalCode,
                    Country = country
                };

                context.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
                context.SaveChanges();

                Console.WriteLine("Cliente creado exitosamente.");
            }
        }

        private static void ReadCustomers()
        {
            using (var context = new EFContext())
            {
                var customers = context.Customers.ToList();
                foreach (var customer in customers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {customer.CustomerID}, Nombre: {customer.CustomerName}, Contacto: {customer.ContactName}, Dirección: {customer.Address}, Ciudad: {customer.City}, Código Postal: {customer.PostalCode}, País: {customer.Country}");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateCustomer()
        {
            using (var context = new EFContext())
            {
                Console.Write("Ingrese el ID del cliente a actualizar: ");
                var updateId = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                var customerToUpdate = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == updateId);
                if (customerToUpdate != null)
                {
                    Console.Write("Nuevo Nombre del Cliente: ");
                    customerToUpdate.CustomerName = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Nuevo Nombre del Contacto: ");
                    customerToUpdate.ContactName = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Nueva Dirección: ");
                    customerToUpdate.Address = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Nueva Ciudad: ");
                    customerToUpdate.City = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Nuevo Código Postal: ");
                    customerToUpdate.PostalCode = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Nuevo País: ");
                    customerToUpdate.Country = Console.ReadLine();

                    context.SaveChanges();

                    Console.WriteLine("Cliente actualizado exitosamente.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cliente no encontrado.");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void DeleteCustomer()
        {
            using (var context = new EFContext())
            {
                Console.Write("Ingrese el ID del cliente a eliminar: ");
                var deleteId = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                var customerToDelete = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == deleteId);
                if (customerToDelete != null)
                {
                    context.Customers.Remove(customerToDelete);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    Console.WriteLine("Cliente eliminado exitosamente.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cliente no encontrado.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//EFContext

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql; // Tener instalado el paquete NuGet Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

namespace DatosEnTablaEntityFrameworkCore
{
    public class EFContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=taller;user=root;password=";

        public DbSet<customers> Customers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(10, 4, 32)));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<customers>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.CustomerID);
                entity.Property(e => e.CustomerID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            });
        }
    }
}

//Customers

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;

namespace DatosEnTablaEntityFrameworkCore
{
    public class customers
    {//La anotación [Key] se coloca sobre una propiedad en una clase de entidad para definir PK
        [Key]
        public BigInteger  CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(37)")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(21)")]
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(47)")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(16)")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(12)")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}


Ten presente que phpmyadmin es solo una herramienta, no un gestor de base de datos. Reemplaza la etiqueta por el SGBD/DBMS que corresponda: MariaDB, MySQL...

trabaja...más o menos no me dice nada  ... o trabaja o no trabaja ... cualquier punto intermedio no es funcional ...
